# Cannot install Octave (Dependency problem)

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, octave

I've tried to install Octave in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit using

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

and it generate a dependency problem

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies:
libosmesa6 : Depends: libosmesa6 (>= 10.2~) but 17.0.70ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
```

and when I tried to install `libomesa6` it says that it need `libglapi`

```
libosmesa6 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2) but 17.0.70ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
```

Then I used apt to install `libglapi-mesa` and I get a message saying it's already up to date

```
libglapi-mesa is already the newest version (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
```

I've tried the solution

[Octave dependency problem on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771747/octave-dependency-problem-on-ubuntu-16-04)

but it seems that I already have 'main server' selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by adding xorg-edgers repository containing the latest version of mesa. I think that libosmesa6 in my main server was obsolete and depended on an older libglapi-mesa package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

Answer (score 1):

> libosmesa6 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2)

It wants an older version of libglapi-mesa. Since you installed the ppa I assume you are getting the newest version of `Octave`. Thus to install it you will need to downgrade libglapi-mesa.

Note: This may cause issues with other programs that depend on libglapi-mesa.

Comment: Can I Install Octave with my version of libglapi-mesa otherwise can I downgrade it

Answer (score 1):

I have `octave 4.0.0-3ubuntu9.1` in 16.04 LTS. It is installed from the standard repository 'universe' without any conflicts. So I suggest that you purge your version of `octave`, remove the PPA and try to install `octave` the standard way.

```
sudo apt purge octave
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:octave/stable

sudo add-apt-repository universe  # maybe/maybe not necessary
sudo apt update
sudo apt install octave
```

You will probably get an older version of octave than from the PPA, but it is tested with Ubuntu, and I hope it has enough features for you.

Comment: I've tried to do so . still the same problem.

Comment: Have you got some other PPA, that causes the conflict with the library? -- What happens after you run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: It gives the same message the same problem

Comment: Have you got some other PPA, that causes the conflict with the library? Or have you installed some other program package via a non-standard method?

Comment: By the way, I have `libglapi-mesa 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2` installed in my system.

Comment: I don't  remember.
I had nearly the same problem with mysql server installation. I don't remember I did solve it

Comment: Maybe There is a PPA causing the problem. How can I know it it's a PPA problem

Comment: You can remove the program package, that depends on that PPA, and then remove that PPA and try again to install `octave`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70218/discussion-between-m-iduoad-and-sudodus).