# How to fix "not installable" unmet dependencies while installing Mosquitto (Ubuntu Server 16.10)?

Tags: server, apt, package-management, dependencies

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 16.10 and was hoping to install Mosquitto. When running `sudo apt-get install mosquitto`, I always get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mosquitto : Depends: sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) but it is not installable or
                      file-rc (>= 0.8.16) but it is not installable
             Depends: libwebsockets3 (>= 1.2) but it is not installable
N: Ignoring file 'index.html' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried following the instructions on [http://mosquitto.org/download](http://mosquitto.org/download/) by first installing the PPA, using `-f` to fix the dependency issues, using aptitude instead per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771780/how-can-i-fix-dependency-problems-in-ubuntu-16-04), changing the download server to Main according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765518/ubuntu-16-04-broken-packages-after-fresh-install) and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main), and I get the same results every time.

I've tried manually installing those dependencies, but predictably they all return an error like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package sysv-rc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  init-system-helpers

N: Ignoring file 'index.html' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'sysv-rc' has no installation candidate
```

And in case there's any question, init-system-helpers is already installed with version 1.45. And I have remembered to use `sudo apt-get update` and have tried rebooting several times.

I'n not completely new to Ubuntu, but I spent 4+ hours on this last night and just can't figure it out. I haven't even found a single person online with the same issue. Any ideas how I might be able to fix it?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer I was looking for, but *an* answer that I found worked was to wipe it and install Ubuntu 16.04. Mosquitto installed with `sudo apt-get install mosquitto` after that.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem.

I believe there is something wrong with the ppa. My solution is removing the mosquitto config in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, which means undo the `apt-add-repository` command. And then install mosquitto from the ubuntu official repo, which version is 1.4.8, depending on libwebsockects7.

The mosquitto from the ppa is version 1.4.9, but it depends on libwebsockets3, which looks much older and has been removed from the official repo. That is why you can not get the deps installed.